# How to estimate the intensity of a multidimensional point process?

Tags: density-function, kernel-smoothing, point-process

Note that for a homogeneous point process the density is just a number, while for an in-homogeneous process it is a function. In addition, how can I distribute that function on a larger study region than the initial points?
***Update 1:***
[image]
Suppose the region `a` is given with intensity functional to x and y coordinates. It is in-homogenous. The region `A` is asked for its intensity based on the region `a`. Indeed region `a` is a subset (sample) of the region `A`. **How?**

***Update 2:***
Suppose I generate a point process on full region `A` as follows (in-homogenous). I select a sub-region and give you only it. I ask you to give me a fully filled region `A` only based on the given sub-point process. What else may I give you to make this possible?
[image]

Comment: 1. What do you know about the stochastic process generating the points? 2. What do you mean; how to *extrapolate* the data?

Comment: @Emre 1) it is unknown! 2) if it was homogenous then intensity is a number readily to be used for any other region. if it was inhomogeneous (it is about the location of points, btw) how? What do you mean by "extrapolation" for point process?

Comment: For inhomogeneous processes, you want to extrapolate—extend—that function to a broader region, right?

Comment: @Emre I may miss something obvious. But have no idea how to extend. Please consider the demonstration added just now. I want to fill the region `A` with point process of the same intensity in the region `a`.

Comment: Without making additional (*very strong*) assumptions about the relationship between the process on $A - a$ and the process on $a$, a full, correct answer is "any way you want."  So to make progress, you will need to provide those assumptions.

Comment: @whuber May you recommend that I generate a full region $A$ with intensity in average the same as the region $a$. Then somehow to condition the region $a$ part of the region $A$. If you see this helping how to make it conditioned?

Comment: I don't follow your comment, Developer.  You can't say *anything* about the process in $A-a$ in general.  You need to make some assumptions.  Research the concepts of "stationary," "ergodic," and "intrinsic" to get some ideas of what might be helpful.